# Using w32tm to resync all computers on a domain

Tags: time, w32time

I've noticed the time on all of our computers seems to be off by about 5 minutes.  I think most computers are set up to sync time with one of our servers.  after running a `net time` or a `w32tm /query /configuration` I've found which server they are looking to.  I have now gone and set the time on that server to a correct time.  Now I am trying to get all the domain computers to resync (something like a `w32tm /resync` on all computers).

Is this something I have to force?  Or will each computer eventually resync by itself?  If I wanted to force that, is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should *not* be changing the time source individually for domain computers. By default they will sync with the Domain Controllers in the domain to ensure that Kerberos (and related services) that are time-sensitive function normally. If you want to use an external time source, you should use `w32tm` to make the Domain Controller holding the PDC Emulator role sync from that source.

That being said, they will sync automatically, assuming your non-domain controller time source is reliable and reachable. If you want to force it, you could always use `psexec` to force remote computers to run the relevant `w32tm` command to resync.

Comment: Just to clarify.  I have not changed the time source on any domain computers.  I checked the time source on a computer then I went to the server they were syncing from and change the time (not the source) on that computer manually.  Now I am trying to get the comain computers to resync with that server.

Comment: @Mr.Monkey If that server that they are looking to for time is not a Domain Controller, then you have a larger issue. If it is, then you can either just wait for them to automatically resync, or force it via `psexec` like I suggested.

Comment: The server they look to is a domain controller.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is also important to make sure that no rogue groupy policy is forcing all the clients to point to an external time source.